# failed to connect to mail server in PHP

Tags: php, email

I have written a small piece of PHP code for sending mail:

```
   <?php
    //define the receiver of the email
    $to = 'rohaanthakare@gmail.com';
    //define the subject of the email
    $subject = 'Hishob email';
    //define the message to be sent. Each line should be separated with \n
    $message = "Hello World!\n\nThis is my first mail.";
    //define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
    $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";
    //send the email
    $mail_sent = mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
    //if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
    echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
    ?>
```

after executing it I got following warning:

> Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\NewHishob\PhpFiles\send_mail.php on line 11
>   Mail failed

I am using a WAMP server and there are two files, INI-DIST and other is INI-RECOMENDED. Which one is important?

I had also gone through php.ini-dist file and for SMTP it contains the following:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
;sendmail_path =
```

Please suggest what I should do? Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: WAMP is not a server. WAMP is a "codename" for the combination of Windows, Apache2 webserver, MySQL dbms and PHP scripting engine.

Comment: Please, correct formatting. There are instructions on the sidebar.

Comment: And what's all this "[CODE]" nonsense?

Answer (score 5):

Do you *have* a SMTP server on that host/port combination ? You can check if something is listening there by doing:

```
$ telnet localhost 25
```

and seeing if `telnet` actually connects.

Answer (score 0):

Also you cannot guarantee that your mail have been sent, as the script doesn't wait for the mailserver to continue.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about this, if you are on localhost and Windows machine, just won't work.
**Use PHPMailer** instead!
I have managed to sent email thru GMail service (just for testing). It is realy simple... Try it
[PHPMailer](http://forum.insanelymac.com/index.php?showtopic=132176)